# how to show all executed commands by directadmin?

Tags: linux, centos7, directadmin

i using linux (centos 7) and panel directadmin(custombuild 2)

how to show all executed commands by directadmin?

if not exist log executing commands by directadmin

how to  log any command executed by user directadmin?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

look at the `/var/log/secure` file. try the below code

`/var/log/secure | grep directadmin`

Then I think you would have to scan the file every few minutes and pull the lines that match the username, this could be written in Python or Bash